# Artifactory + TeamCity : How to deploy custom JAR?

Tags: maven, docker, teamcity, artifactory

I am building a maven project **within** a Docker container as a TeamCity job configuration.

(This is necessary because the maven project builds a JNA library -- so it must be built on a specific distro)

At the end of running the docker container, I'm left with the *target* folder of the maven module which contains the JAR & associated other files (i.e. class files etc..)

I'm stumped onto now how to get this JAR published to Artifactory? All the integration with TeamCity seems to be if the JAR was built with the maven runner specifically

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you use `mvn deploy` to build and deploy an artifact with Maven. It is transferred to the Maven repository that you specified in your distributionManagement.

With Artifactory, you can also use the `artifactory-maven-plugin` for deployment.